# Last Day of Each Month Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table X which holds data for each day for a brand. The data for each day is cumulative i.e. sales data for 3 will have data for 1, 2 and 3. Thus data for the last day of each month will be the sales for that month for that brand and company. I want to get the sum of all the sales for that brand for the last 3 months excluding the current month on the last day of each month.
i.e for March: I want sales from 31st Jan 2019 + 28th Feb 2019 + 31st Dec 2018 for each brand and company.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want all the code to be written by someone, you can bargain freelancers hopefully. Otherwise, please share what you've tried.

Comment: Include sample data and expected output.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show us what you've tried so far? This seems like a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MSSQL you can use EOMONTH function, example is as under

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(255) = '2/24/2019';  
SELECT EOMONTH ( @date ) AS Result;
```

for MySQL you can use LAST_DAY function

```
SELECT LAST_DAY('2019-02-24');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say name of your column representing the sales date is "sales_date", then the following predicate will give you the days you're interested in:

```
sales_date in (
    dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 2, 0)),
    dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0)),
    dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0))
)
```